# SQL command to map data from one column to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Suppose my table looks like this

```
[   name, number, firstname]    
[foo:bar,    123,          ]
[bar:foo,    456,          ]
```

I want to split the name field at ':' and use the first part as the 'firstname' column. Furthermore, I want this to be permanent, rather than just a result set.  How would I do that?

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

I'm aware that variants of this question have been asked before, but they all seem to deal with merely selecting the data, and I mean to update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a view that does this then use the view for future selects.

```
CREATE VIEW split name AS
SELECT 
SUBSTRING(name, 1, CHARINDEX(':',  name, 1) - 1) as firstname, 
RTRIM(SUBSTRING(name,  CHARINDEX(':',  name, 1)+1,100)) as surname, number
FROM myTable
```

Alternatively,

```
UPDATE myTable
SET firstname = SUBSTRING(name, 1, CHARINDEX(':',  name, 1) - 1) 
FROM myTable
```

Comment: In your second solution, is 'name' the table name or the column name?

Comment: why is 'name' the statement block for UPDATE if name is unchanged?

Comment: I'll blame the suddenly slow WiFi

Answer (score 1):

```
select substring(name, 1, Charindex(':', name) - 1) as first_name,
    substring(name, Charindex(':', name) + 1, LEN(name)) as  last_name,
    number
from my_table
```

Comment: could you explain what is actually going on there?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by having a computed column for `firstname` - this means that you do not need to actually persist first name, but you can treat it as if it were any other column.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
    [name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [firstname]  AS (substring([name],(0),charindex(':',[name])))
)
```